# Using JavaToolkit for RallyRestAPI QueryFilter to filter based on Id

Tags: java, rally

I am trying to filter `QueryRequest` using `QueryFilter` from **Rally Rest API**:

```
storyRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("FormattedID", "starts with", "E"));
storyRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("FormattedID", "contains", "E"));
```

However, it does **not work**. Please let me know what operator I can use here.

Comment: What does "*not work*" mean? Create a [mcve] and explain the problem in detail. If you get error messages, provide the full error including stacktrace.

Comment: You won't be able to filter on the Prefix portion of the FormattedID.  From the Web Services Help documentation for FormattedID:  "In queries, only include the integer portion and omit the prefix."

I am wondering what your use case is for this query, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thank you Michael B, I was trying to find all issues that has the prefix E. This is to find Epics that has prefix E to the FormattedID.  Currently I am using this:             QueryRequest epicRequest = new QueryRequest("epic");

Comment: new QueryFilter("FormattedID", "contains", "\"E\""));  or (new QueryFilter("FormattedID", "contains", "E")) could work I guess.